# How to update a datalist in a form?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to update a `p:datalist` after user enters some informations to pop up. But i cant update partially my form.

Here is my .xhtml

```
<h:body>
    <center>
    <h:form style="width:500px">
        <p:tabView>
            <p:tab title="Profil">
                <p:panel>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">   
                    <p:dataList id="ortaklar" value="#{ortakController.ortakList}" var="ortak" type="ordered">  
                        #{ortak.isim}, #{ortak.soyad}  
                    </p:dataList> 
                </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="Detay"></p:tab>
            <p:tab title="Kayıt"></p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
    </h:form>
    <p:dialog header="Yeni Ortak" widgetVar="ortakDlg">  
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText for="ortakIsim" value="İsim:" />  
                <h:inputText id="ortakIsim" value="#{ortakController.person.isim}" />  

                <h:outputText for="ortakSoyad" value="Soyad:" />  
                <h:inputText id="ortakSoyad" value="#{ortakController.person.soyad}" />  
            </h:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton value="Ekle" actionListener="#{ortakController.addToList}" update="ortaklar""/>
            <p:commandButton id="sil" value="Sil" type="reset" />
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
    </center>
</h:body>
```

Here is my bean;

```
@ManagedBean(name = "ortakController")
public class OrtakController {

    private static List<Person> ortakList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    private Person person = new Person();

    public OrtakController() {
    }

    public void addToList(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        ortakList.add(person);
    }

    public List<Person> getOrtakList() {
        return ortakList;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person currentKisi) {
        this.person = currentKisi;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
}
```

Basically i added an item to pop up also i want to add this item to datalist in my form.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed tabView parent form. And it works. I think it is kind of a scope problem of forms.

Comment: I removed the `[SOLVED]` from the title of your question. Please check the "answered" icon next to this answer to indicate it solved your problem. Thanks.

Comment: i added it,because i have 2 days to accept my own answer. But thanks anyway

Comment: Yeah, two days is a bit long, but the `[ALL CAPS]` tags inside the question titles cause my eyes to bleed :P